# Changes for py2cairo ebuild to activate xpyb in build

Tags: compiling, gentoo, packaging, funtoo

I would like to build `qtile` for *Funtoo/Gentoo* and there is also a nice py2cairo ebuild, but it misses an option for xpyb, so it builds without those options, now my interesst is to fork that ebuild and set it manually that I and others too can be able to use qtile on funtoo/gentoo.

Would be nice if someone can point me in the right direction or provide me with a fix for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any other knowledge you're missing other than [creating your own overlay](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=3&chap=5)?

- create package category directory in overlay (there's probably some command that creates this automatically when copying in the next step)
- copy package directory from portage into overlay
- modify ebuild
- run `ebuild package.ebuild digest`
- `emerge -va package`

Comment: ok, that far I already got, but the problem is pycairo is a multilevel ebuild, it builds for python2 and python3, so the question is more precisely how can I activate the XPYB-Switches in the ebuild, might be that I ran into a thought problem when doing the changes...

Comment: so "emerge xpyb" on your own before emerging pycairo doesn't make things work?

Comment: it looks like this a dual build system capable package. autotools definitely seem to be a lot more verbose than waf is, and configuring with waf, i have no idea so far whether it is actually finding xpyb or not.

you could just take a shot at a simple ebuild using eautoreconf instead of all the other waf crap that's in it right now.

Comment: nope emerge xpyb doesn't change a thing, did it 4 times and still the error with QTile is py2cairo without xpyb support. trying to get a single build python 2 with eautoreconf and stuff... uncool that it is so badly behaving but see if I get a fix for it...